# Image in <title>

Tags: html, css, image, title

As far as I read, the `<title>` element just accepts plain text.

[image: title image]
[image: title image 2]

So how they managed to add an image to it?

Comment: If you mean the snow-flake that is not an image. It is a unicode emoji characther. See https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Comment: @David that's not a favicon.

Comment: It is plain text, using unicode Emojis. See https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: I guess it depends on which "image" the OP is referring to.  The question is unclear about that.

Comment: @David the images shows both a snowflake, I think it's clear =/

Comment: @David c'mon, the code on the right clearly shows a snowflake, what else might they be talking about?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: They *might* be talking about the image shown on the left which appears to be part of the "title" in the browser tab but isn't in the `<title>` element in the HTML.  This exchange is the very nature of what "unclear" means.  Open to interpretation and viewed differently by different readers.  Adding clarity to the question would have taken very little effort on the OP's part.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers, I didn't know that =) Another thing that I learn today =)

Comment: @David I asked my coworker what he thought the question was about and he told me it was about the favicon, so I guess you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Emoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) **are** plain text.

You can enter characters like ✌️(U+270C : VICTORY HAND followed by U+FE0F : VARIATION SELECTOR-16), just like any other character.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, despite the -3 D=